# Searching large Excel files and handling large amounts of data efficiently

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, search

I've started on project, here's what I have:

Excel file (exl1) containing 450K records, with 50K more each month.

exl1 format

```
invoice#|Box#|Serial-#1|Serial-#2|5-val-enum#1|5-val-enum#2|10-val-enum|4-val-enum|timestamp
```

ex1:
    `abc123|box1|0987654321|A123456789|Plant|Tree|PersonName1|North|DateTime.Now`

ex2:
`qwe345|box9|12345678901234567890|#NA|Animal|Cat|PersonName1|South|DT.Now`

Excel file (exl2) containing roughly 50K records. (named searchcVal for purpose of explanation)
exl2 format
Serial1

ex1a:
`A123456789`

ex1b:
`0987654321`

ex2a:
`12345678901234567890`

Here's what I have to do:

1. Compare each value in exl2(searchval) to either Serial#1 or Serial#2 depending on the value of 5-val-enum#1 of exl1 (example1 = Plant  , example2 = Animal)
2. if searchVal starts with [a-z] search serial2 else search serial1 ; so, with searchVal ex1a search col3 and serachval ex1b search col2

   ```
       if (exl1.Rows[columnHeader][col4].ToString() == "Plant")
       {
           string rowVal = exl2.Rows[rowIterator][col0].ToString();
           if (regex.IsMatch(rowVal[0].ToString()))//checks to see if serial1 or  serial2
           {
               if (rowVal == exl1.Rows[rowIterator][col3].ToString())
               {
                   //add matched row to ResultsDT
               }
               else
               {  //next row
               }
           }
           else
           { //search col2 with same procedure
           }
       }
       else
       {//search col2
       }
   ```
3. for the sake of explanation lets say Person1 matched 400 Plants of which 100 were trees, 100 were bushes , 100 were grasses and 100 were flowers and
   he matched 400 Animals of which 100 were cats, dogs, snakes and birds each. with these matches I'd like to summarize it to the output of
   SUMMARY1 : PersonName|Plants|Animals|category3|Category4|Category5  with a more detailed one for each of the categories like 
   SUMMARY 2: PersonName|Trees|Bushes|Grasses|Flowers leading to SUMM1 : Person1|400|400|x|n|y SUMM2(plants only) : Person1|100|100|100|100
4. Most importantly : do all this without killing the PC it's running on for 3 hours while it computes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the question here is "how can I perform this tasks efficiently?"

The answer is, you shouldn't. It sounds like you are trying to do [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) on the cheap (except that, well, it may not be happening strictly online), and there are a lot of solutions already available for this.

Since you already have an established procedure of using an excel spreadsheet, [PALO](http://www.palo.net/en/) may serve your needs (**edit:** it's free).

Alternatively, what you have there is a denormalized set of records; if you normalize it into several sets & enter it into a database (using a script, obviously), you can let your database take care of the intensive computations. **Edit:** There are a lot of free databases you can use ([SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) is a language, not a brand). E.g. [PostgrSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)

If you insist on parsing the files & analyzing the files yourself, then I suggest you modify your algorithm to do 2 things:

<s>Firstly, get your 50k set of records to fit into as little memory as is reasonable possible. Obviously, you don't want to store your records as 50k strings: parse them, and build up a memory structure which lets you access only the information you need.</s> **Edit:**  Nevermind, misunderstood your input data.

Secondly, modify your algorithm so that it can be run piecemeal. Currently you have 1 set of 50k records, and another set of 450k records, and it sounds like you expect to run your program each month (or more frequently) on the full set of records + whatever records have been added to the 450k set of records. If you start storing incremental results, you can structure your script so that it processes (for example) up to 10k records at a time from your 450k record set at a time, and run several instances of your script in sequence, you can avoid re-analyzing the whole 450k of records every month and also have a handy way to stop & start the process midway (using some kind of parent script).

For a more complex approach, look [Divide and Conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) as it applies to algorithms.

Comment: forgive me if I sound like an idiot but is there a reason for the proposed memory structure? I have to go through all the records so all the info is necessary.
Also, are there any books you'd recommend on this?

Comment: Ah my mistake, I understood your set of 50k records to be in the same format as your larger records set (your explanation is a little hard to understand); if it consists entirely of strings up to 20 characters in length, then there's not much more you can do to make that side of things faster. [CLR's Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) is more or less the goto book for algorithm ABCs, but I suspect it's a bit heavy weight / low ROI for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe my C# is just rusty, but it isn't clear to me from your sample how you're reading your excel file.. are you reading a .xls(x) file using a library (and if so, does that library dump the whole file into memory, or does it read from disk as needed), or are you parsing a csv export (or similar) of your data?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options:

1. Treat excel as the database and check its performance - here is how to do this: http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/Excel-ADO.NET-Database.aspx.
2. If option no 1 is too slow import this data to a real database (ms sql, mysql, postgresql, etc.), add appropriate indexes and perform your searches in the db. The excel would be treated just as a datasource for an initial import.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the ratio of Excel updates/Queries run, it might be a good idea to simply read the values into an sql server database and query/process the data there? I would imagine that it takes some time to read the values into sql server, but the queries should take no time...

Comment: I'd dearly love to do that , the only thing is I have almost no experience with Sql Server and even if I did the company I'm working for can't afford the licence